# AFOpenFlowView touchesEnded ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an AFOpenFlowView (the coverflow implementation that subclasses UIView) in a xib file with the owner as a UIViewController. However, I notice the AFOpenFlowView has no events to connect IBActions to. I'm basically trying to connect the TouchesEnded event from the AFOpenFlowView to an IBAction method. When I look inside the AFOpenFlowView classes, I notice there are methods for touchesEnded, touchesBegan, etc, however they dont seem to be showing up in Interface Builder. Any help would be much appreciated!